# Can anyone identify this white air/spacecraft please?

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone help me identify this air/spacecraft please?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is part of the Justice League Javelin 
from [76028-1: Darkseid Invasion](https://brickset.com/sets/76028-1/Darkseid-Invasion)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, thought it was comic book related but didn't think of Justice League.